# Is log-sum-exp a contraction

Tags: lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the log-sum-exp (lse) function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as 
$lse(x) = \tau \log \sum_{i=1}^n \exp(\frac{x_i}{\tau})$, where $\tau > 0$ is a temperature. Is lse an infinity norm contraction?
In other words, is there an $L \in (0, 1)$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$|lse(x) - lse(y)| \leq L ||x - y||_\infty$$
From some literature search I find it holds for $L=1$, but is it possible for $L < 1$? I guess $L$ may be a function of $\tau$. I did some simulation and found it seems true and $L$ is not monotonic w.r.t. $\tau$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do better than $L=1$. To see this, let us first get rid of the $\tau$. Using the fact that $\tau\neq 0$ and scaling the coordinates by $\tau$, it clearly follows that proving the displayed inequality in the question is the same as showing that
$$
\tag{1} |lse(\tau x ) - lse(\tau y)| \leq L || \tau x - \tau y ||_\infty, \text{ for all  } x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Writing $(1)$ explicitly, gives
$$
\tag{2} \left|\log \sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} - \log \sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{y_i} \right| \leq L || x - y||.
$$

In dimension $n=1$, $(2)$ is reduced to
$$
|\log e^x - \log e^y | = |x - y|,
$$
hence $L=1$ is the Lipschitz constant when $n=1$. In higher dimensions, for instance, $L=1$ is realized on points having all their $n$ coordinates $0$ except one.

To see that $L=1$ actually satisfies $(1)$, denote $f(x) = \log \sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}$ and observe that for any $1\leq i \leq n$ we have
$$
f_{x_i}(x) = \frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1} + ... + e^{x_n}},
$$
where $f_{x_i}$ is the $i$-th partial derivative of $f$.
Hence, from the intermediate value theorem for some $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ lying on the segment $[x,y]$ we have
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |\nabla f(c) \cdot (x-y)| \leq ||x-y||_\infty \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_{x_i}(c) = ||x-y||_\infty,
$$
which proves that $L=1$ is indeed the Lipschitz constant for $lse$.

Comment: Can we show that eq (2) for dimensions $n>1$ for arbitrary $L$?

Comment: @amj, $(2)$ is proved in any dimension for $L=1$ and hence for any $L \geq 1$. The counterexample discussed in the text shows that the inequality is not correct for $L < 1$.

Comment: But does it hold for vectors with non-zero values at all indices?

Comment: @amj, the proof of the (positive) inequality, i.e. showing that $L = 1$ (and hence $L \geq 1$) works is for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It is the counterexample, for the case $L<1$, that is constructed for a special type of points of $\mathbb{R}^n$.